# Inline print with list comprehension

Tags: python, printing, list-comprehension

I need to print some stuff only when an object's boolean property (an object which is in an array) is set to True. I'm currently trying:

```
    print("Points of Interest: " + (" ".join([str(poi.name) for poi in currentRoom.pointsOfInterest] if [poi.found for poi in currentRoom.pointsOfInterest] else 0)))
```

I'm missing something here, as the `str(poi.name)` gets printed despite the object's bool property (poi.found) being set to false.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[poi.found for poi in currentRoom.pointsOfInterest]` creates a list. If there are any objects in it, it will be truthy. These objects can even be falsey - the overall list will still evaluate as truthy, as long as the list isn't empty. You will need to use `any` or `all`, depending on the exact behavior you'd like to see:

```
>>> if [0, 0]: print('y')
...
y
>>> if any([0,0]): print('y')
...
>>> if all([0,0]): print('y')
...
>>> if any([]): print('y')
...
>>> if all([]): print('y')
...
y
>>> if any([0,1]): print('y')
...
y
>>> if all([0,1]): print('y')
...
>>> if any([1,1]): print('y')
...
y
>>> if all([1,1]): print('y')
...
y
```